# How to find specific script tag from a webpage using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and beautifulsoup. I'm trying to find a json data inside script tag. My problem is the webpage contains many script tags.

I need to get this script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
var data = {
'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SL1003_.jpg",
"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lv4ReBL4L._AC_US40_.jpg",
"large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lv4ReBL4L._AC_.jpg",
"main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY355_.jpg":[355,355],
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY450_.jpg":[450,450],
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX425_.jpg":[425,425],
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX466_.jpg":[466,466],
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX522_.jpg":[522,522],
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX569_.jpg":[569,569],
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX679_.jpg":[679,679]},
"variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SL1005_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41shdN1aAoL._AC_US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41shdN1aAoL._AC_.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SY355_.jpg":[355,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SY450_.jpg":[450,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX522_.jpg":[522,522],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX569_.jpg":[569,569],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX679_.jpg":[679,679]},"variant":"PT01","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SL1005_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pt8OOHsaL._AC_US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pt8OOHsaL._AC_.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SY355_.jpg":[355,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SY450_.jpg":[450,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX522_.jpg":[522,522],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX569_.jpg":[569,569],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX679_.jpg":[679,679]},"variant":"PT02","lowRes":null}]},
'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},
'holderRatio': 1.0,
'holderMaxHeight': 700,
'heroImage': {'initial': []},
'heroVideo': {'initial': []},
'spin360ColorData': {'initial': {}},
'spin360ColorEnabled': {'initial': 0},
'spin360ConfigEnabled': false,
'spin360LazyLoadEnabled': false,
'showroomEnabled': false,
'showroomViewModel': {'initial': {}},
'playVideoInImmersiveView':true,
'useTabbedImmersiveView':true,
'totalVideoCount':'0',
'videoIngressATFSlateThumbURL':'',
'mediaTypeCount':'0',
'atfEnhancedHoverOverlay' : true,
'winningAsin': 'B08373YYCM',
'weblabs' : {},
'aibExp3Layout' : 1,
'aibRuleName' : 'frank-powered',
'acEnabled' : true,
'dp60VideoPosition': 0,
'dp60VariantList': '',
'dp60VideoThumb': '',
'dp60MainImage': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY355_.jpg',

'airyConfig' :A.$.parseJSON('{"jsUrl":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/js/airy.skin._CB485981857_.js","cssUrl":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/css/beacon._CB485971591_.css","swfUrl":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/flash/AiryBasicRenderer._CB485925577_.swf","foresterMetadataParams":{"marketplaceId":"A2VIGQ35RCS4UG","method":"Kitchen.ImageBlock","requestId":"4MGH16D6R7WCR018779W","session":"259-8488476-1037262","client":"Dpx"}}')

};
A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
return data;
});
</script>
```

How i can get this script tag which starts "P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){" from the webpage using reqular expression ?

Comment: please update with your best attempt using [edit] and explain what isn't working

Answer (score 1):

you can get all `script` tags by

```
page = requests.get("url")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("script")
```

and then you could have your **filtering** as

```
your_script_tag = [x for x in results if str(x).__contains__("P.when('A').register")]

print(your_script_tag)
```

Comment: thank you ali !.  I want only 'colorImages': {}  and save as json, how it is possible ?

Comment: my main purpose is to get images.